# Guard always redirects to the default route

Tags: angular, observable, guard, canactivate

I have a guard that checks a user's session.
I am creating an observable from a promise and returning that observable.

Unfortunately the router always redirects me to homepage on refresh.
I guess it has to do with the observable as when I simply navigate, it enters the if and returns the 'Observalbe.of(true)', which works.

```
@Injectable()
export default class SessionGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.hasSessionChecked) {
      return Observable.of(true).take(1);
    }

    const obs = Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.getSession());
    return obs.map((session) => {
      this.authService.setUserSession(session);
      return true;
    }).take(1);
  }
}
```

I have tried replacing the observable with a 'return true' and everything works as expected.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `canActivate` is supposed to return a boolean.

Why would you want to use an Observable ?

Comment: that isnt true, the definition of canActivate in the interface allows 3 return types: export interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate line 15 of the first example.

Comment: Just the line beneath it, you can see that it returns the canActivate function from permission. See what this function returns.

Comment: In this example, it does return a boolean. But, as you can see on line 15, it can return a promise or observable that resolve to a boolean or a boolean.

Comment: I will ask you to think for a second. If this function returns **only** the result of another function, then what it can return ?

Comment: I need the canActivate to return an observable so the route resolver will wait until the http call is completed. How can you do that by returning a boolean?

Comment: You call your service, and return the boolean in the subscribe. If it successes, you return true, otherwise you return false ! But returning an empty observable won't resolve it, this is why it doesn't work.

Comment: do something like `return this.myService.myMethod('your args').subscribe(success => true, failure => false);`

Comment: that would be wrong, in that case you would return a subscription, not a boolean value

Comment: Then just lose the first return (I can't test what I'm writing, and I don't know the syntax by heart, sorry)

Comment: The service uses a promise. The promise is resolved but after, the router redirects me to /

Comment: Well it's not related to your guard anymore then. If the return works but it redirects you where you don't want, try changing the "where you don't want".

Comment: I thought about that. But the weird part is that if I have a simple "return true", the router works as expected. That's what made me think it's about the guard.

Comment: Well it's not **about** the guard, but maybe **because of** it. Maybe you get redirected to `/` if you don't resolve your Promise ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146856/discussion-between-bogdan-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 0):

**First**, the definition of `canActivate` is the following:

```
export interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

So you should add the parameters in the function.

**Second**, if you are going to return an observable and only an observable, then change the return type to just observable. If you want a mix, then you could leave more than one return type.

**Third**, remove the take() operator and refactor the guard to look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export default class SessionGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.hasSessionChecked) {
      return true;
    }
    const obs = Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.getSession());
    return obs.map(session => {
      this.authService.setUserSession(session);
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

As @trichetriche suggested, I have replaced the observable with a promise and returned that.

It's working great now.

```
return this.authService.getSession().then(
  data => {
    this.authService.setUserSession(data);
    return true;
  },
  err => false,
);
```